# AWS Cognito - custom challenge not triggered

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm defining a custom challenge on user authentication. I created a few lambdas:

#### tutoring-define-auth-challenge

```
"use strict";

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    // throw new Error("tutoring-define-auth-challenge");
    if (event.request.session.length == 1 && event.request.session[0].challengeName == 'SRP_A') {
        event.response.issueTokens = false;
        event.response.failAuthentication = false;
        event.response.challengeName = 'PASSWORD_VERIFIER';
    } else if (event.request.session.length == 2 && event.request.session[1].challengeName == 'PASSWORD_VERIFIER' && event.request.session[1].challengeResult == true) {
        event.response.issueTokens = false;
        event.response.failAuthentication = false;
        event.response.challengeName = 'CUSTOM_CHALLENGE';
    } else if (event.request.session.length == 3 && event.request.session[2].challengeName == 'CUSTOM_CHALLENGE' && event.request.session[2].challengeResult == true) {
        event.response.issueTokens = true;
        event.response.failAuthentication = false;
    } else {
        event.response.issueTokens = false;
        event.response.failAuthentication = true;
    }

    // Return to Amazon Cognito
    callback(null, event);
}
```

#### tutoring-create-auth-challenge

```
"use strict";

const publicKey = require('./public');
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    //throw new Error("tutoring-create-auth-challenge");
    event.response.privateChallengeParameters = { key: publicKey.key };
    return event;
};
```

and configured them as triggers in the user pools
[image]

The problem is that those lambdas aren't triggered. I added errors in each of them (see commented out code) but I was able to register and log in without any problem.

What I want to do is add a new challenge with checking a custom JWT token (instead of verification code sent by email).

What else do I have to do to make it work? I checked cloudwatch and could be able to find only logs from manual lambda's executions.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please show which commands are you using to trigger the custom challenge?
 
Recently I've implemented a similar flow to what you have described in `define-auth`. A couple of things I'd like to share:

1. This [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html) was very helpful(**Use SRP Password Verification in Custom Authentication Flow** section)
2. If you are familiar with Java I highly recommend you to have a look at this nice [utility](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cognito-java-desktop-app/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/sample/cognitoui/AuthenticationHelper.java#L176) (similar code can be found for python and javascript) that can be used for custom flow invocations. For that, I believe you need to update `AuthFlowType` [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cognito-java-desktop-app/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/sample/cognitoui/AuthenticationHelper.java#L212) to `CUSTOM_AUTH`.
    Also, this utility helps with `PASSWORD_CLAIM_SIGNATURE` and `PASSWORD_CLAIM_SECRET_BLOCK` calculations.